# Show that the restriction is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, diagonalization

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and for each $\displaystyle{f=\sum_{i=0}^ma_it^i\in \mathbb{K}[t]}$ let $\displaystyle{f'=\sum_{i=1}^mia_it^{i-1}\in \mathbb{K}[t]}$ be the formal derivative of $f$.

Let \begin{equation*}\phi : \mathbb{K}[t]\rightarrow \mathbb{K}[t], \ f\mapsto tf' \ \text{ und } \ \psi : \mathbb{K}[t]\rightarrow \mathbb{K}[t], \ f\mapsto (tf)'\end{equation*}

I have shown that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are linear operators of $\mathbb{K}$-vector space $\mathbb{K}[t]$.

Let  $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We consider the set $V_n:=\left \{f\in \mathbb{K}[t]\mid \deg (f)\leq n\right \}$.

I have shown that $V_n$ is a $(n+1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{K}[t]$, with $V_n\leq_{\phi}\mathbb{K}[t]$ and $V_n\leq_{\psi}\mathbb{K}[t]$.

> How can we show that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the restriction $\phi_n$ of $\phi$ on $V_n$ is diagonalizable (and respective for $\psi_n$) ?

Comment: what is the meaning of $\leq_\phi$?

Comment: It is ment that it is a subspace and it is $\phi$-invariant @Azif00

Answer (score 1):

Hint.
What's the matrix of $\Phi_n$ in the basis $(1,t,t^2,\ldots,t^n)$ ?

Comment: Does that matrix contain the corresponding coefficients to the elements of the basis?

Comment: This matrix is diagonal

Comment: This matrix has at the diagonal the coefficients of the basis and every other element is $0$ ?

Comment: $\Phi_n(t^i)=it^i$. So, if $(m_{i,j})_{0\leqslant i,j \leqslant n}$ is the matrix of $\Phi_n$ in the basis $(1,t,\ldots,t^n)$, we have: if $i\neq j$ , $m_{i,j}=0$   and $m_{i,i}=i$.

Comment: Ahh ok! From that we get also that the eigenvalues of $\phi_n$ are the eigenvalues of $m$, i.e. the diagonal elements $i$, right?

Comment: This would mean that the spectrum of $\phi_n$ is $\{0,1,\ldots , n\}$, right?

Comment: Yes for the two statements.